# How to compare row data to my input data in sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sqlite, compare, rows

Im having trouble comparing if a certain data exist in my table based on my input. Lets say my input data is:

```
x = 1
```

then my table consists of 6 rows of numbers:

```
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

I compare my input just like this:

```
c.execute("""SELECT num from tb_numbers""")
table = c.fetchall()
if x in table:
  do something....
```

After running, it does not go in the if statement. What am i doing wrong here? Note: "num" in tb_numbers is an INTEGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.execute("""SELECT num from tb_numbers""")
table = c.fetchall()

x = 1

for each_value in table:
    if each_value[0] == x:
        print("Yeah! Find: {0}".format(each_value[0]))
```

If you're looking for just one value, you can end the for loop after finding the value to deliver performance.

```
for each_value in table:
    if each_value[0] == x:
        print("Yeah! Find: {0}".format(each_value[0]))
        break
```